# How can deity plants like Tulsi and Rice be reconciled with the destined progression of the soul?

Tags: scripture, vishnu-purana, plants

The Viṣṇu Purāṇa states souls are destined to proceed through successive births, but deity plants like Tulsi and Rice are surely the zenith already.

> The gods in heaven are beheld by the inhabitants of hell, as they move with their heads inverted; whilst the god, as they cast their eyes downwards, behold the sufferings of those in hell. The various stages of existence, Maitreya, are inanimate things, fish, birds, animals, men, holy men, gods, and liberated spirits; each in succession a thousand degrees superior to that which precedes it: and through these stages the beings that are either in heaven or in hell are **destined to proceed**, until final emancipation be obtained. That sinner goes to Naraka who neglects the due expiation of his guilt.

My guess for solving the apparent contradiction is that the destined progression of souls only forces body type change in Naraka (and maybe Svarga).

https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/the_vishnu_purana_book_ii.htm#fnA302

Comment: You are confusing deity and deity plants etc. For eg Cow is worshipped, but the soul inside a cow is not a deity. Tulsi is worshipped because that plant is presided over by a deity. Buut the individual souls in the plants are not in zenith imo, they will also have to progress thorugh other life forms.

Comment: @MrGreenGold But the deity Tulsi is also a plant due to having plant bodies. Thus she/he will be breaking the progression trend.

Comment: No you are confusinf the presiding deity with the soul. There is presiding deity Tulsi. She is God. But there are individual souls living in Tulsi plants. See the presiding deity of hands is Lord Indra. So your hands are presided over by Lord Indra. But you are not a God. Humans are presided by Vasudeva deity I guess. But Humans are not Gods. Presiding deity is different from Individual souls.

Comment: https://rkmdelhi.org/articles/own-responsibility/

Comment: @MrGreenGold Deities are different from what they preside over like Indra with hands, but not what their name stands for. For example, Agni is one with fire, because praises of Agni treat him as such.

Comment: Agni is an object. Wherever living objects are worshipped, there are two things presiding deity and the individual soul residing in the living being. Are you saying the soul in two different tulsi plants is the same soul ? Where did you get this theory, you are making it on your own.

Comment: @MrGreenGold They are the same soul as plants being able to form cuttings and not having brains makes no sense unless they don't need a physical connection to control their bodies. Plus I'm not making it up Anna is described as being the physical form of Vishnu thus having the same soul           https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502218.html

Comment: No no I think there is genuine confusion here between presiding deities and actual souls living in each being. Hkw about a ciw being worshipped?? All cows have one single soul? Anna is the physical form of Vishnu, but inside it there are other souls in each rice plant.

Comment: @MrGreenGold Cows don't have the same soul unless some crazy science is used, but plants do. The "individual souls" in plants don't do anything.

Comment: @MrGreenGold BTW cancer is an example of animals turning plant-like and being single souled. That's why the recent appearance of transmissible cancers is proof of reincarnation (and karma).

Comment: @MrGreenGold Actually all life is single-souled across its body/bodies, which is why the soul is able to control its body without a single control point, especially organisms without brains.